# How to correct indentation in HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html

Given a string like this:

```
' \n <div id="a">\n <span class="b">\n<span>Hello</span>\n\n\n</span> <input type="text">\n  \n</div>\n '
```

I'd like to format it like this:

```
<div id="a">
  <span class="b">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

i.e. the result should be: (assume 2 spaces for indentation)

```
'<div id="a">\n  <span class="b">\n    <span>\n      Hello\n    </span>\n  </span>\n  <input type="text">\n</div>'
```

What's the most elegant way to achieve this? Is there an established way to do that?

**Note:**

- I'm not looking for HTML syntax highlighting, just indentation correction
- I'm not looking to support the whole HTML spec, correcting basic HTML like the example above would suffice

Comment: What would you do if the input is `<div><span></div></span>`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol probably cry because that is invalid html!

Comment: I don't really care about invalid HTML, so any result will be good enough.

Comment: @Pete Well absolutely. Personally I would reject the input outright, but what does OP want to do with it?

Comment: a google search for html prettify turned up (this)[https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify ] may be useful

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Personally, I would suggest parsing the HTML string into a DOM object, and then reconstructing the HTML in the format that you want. This may seem like a daunting task, but it will be significantly easier than trying to manipulate strings.

Comment: Also what happens say when the elements are styled as inline block elements and adding spaces between them breaks the design / layout? And just as a note, the only people who benefit from this are people who view the source.  People who just use the site will have only have a slower site due to the extra processing

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sounds like a good plan. Would you like to suggest a possible implementation?

Comment: Why? Is this for humans to read example code?

Comment: The implementation is not that complicated. You take DOM structure,  iterate recursively and just append text nodes.

Comment: You can\`t do this properly without a spec. You will fail, for example at the first `<iframe srcdoc="<ul><li>"></iframe>` fragment. You NEED TO parse the whole HTML to be able to make properly indentation. DOM structure will be a good start.

Comment: @Pete That's a good point! I think it should be possible to do the job without breaking the layout. I guess we can check whether there is a whitespace (one or more), and only if yes, add the `\n`. Does this make sense? I updated the question. If you still think it's problematic, could you show an example?

Comment: @RichBradshaw I use [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/) to highlight an  HTML fragment and show it to the user. The problem is that prismjs doesn't fix the indentation for me, so I need to do this myself before passing the HTML string to prismjs for highlighting.

Comment: What about [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive function I wrote, which I think might help you to achieve what you are after.

```
function process(str) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.trim();

    return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
}

function format(node, level) {

    var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
        indentAfter  = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
        textNode;

    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

        textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
        node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);

        format(node.children[i], level);

        if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
            textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
            node.appendChild(textNode);
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
process(str);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var str = '<div id="a"><span class="b"><span>Hello</span></span><input type="text"><p><b>b <i>italic</i></b></p></div>';

function process(str) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str.trim();

  return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
}

function format(node, level) {
  var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
    indentAfter = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
    textNode;

  for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
    textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
    node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);

    format(node.children[i], level);

    if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
      textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
      node.appendChild(textNode);
    }
  }

  return node;
}

document.querySelector('#out').innerText = process(str);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1gf07wap/

Comment: Thanks! Looks close to what I'm looking for. However, your function creates too many new lines. Have a look at these 2 example inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/3gLxLhs3/

Comment: It's because you input has weird new lines and spaces. it's easy to fix the function to remove leading white spaces though.

Comment: thanks, u saved my day :)

Answer (score 6):

The [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) tool can work with html, and has an api. It's probably the easiest way to do what you want.

After installing it with node:

```
var beautify_html = require('js-beautify').html;

result = beautify_html(htmlstring);
```

To use it in a browser, you need to include all the beautify*.js scripts in [this directory](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/tree/master/js/lib) and use `window.html_beautify`.

**[DEMO](http://requirebin.com/?gist=b4d994eb60831d609800)**

Comment: This beautifier sucks, for example, when you input `<!doctype html><head><title> </title><ul><li>a<li>b</ul>`, you get incorrect results. Downvote from me.

Comment: @Benio Really? I believe it's the same thing used [here](http://jsbeautifier.org/), and it gives a good result to me.

Comment: Yes. I tested it right on this site. The second `li` is incorrectly more indented than the first one. `<!doctype html>\n\n<head>\n\t<title> </title>\n\t<ul>\n\t\t<li>a\n\t\t\t<li>b</ul>` is not a good indentation.

Comment: @Benio That's because your HTML doesn't have any closing tags, and it thinks that the `li` is inside the other `li`. It only works in browsers because the parser in browsers are more lenient. You can't really expect much from invalid html.

Comment: @parchment the closing `li` tag is optional so the only thing invalid about the code Benio has pasted is that it does not have `body` tags and a closing `head` tag.  [From the spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) An li element’s end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.

Comment: @Pete Ah, I didn't know about that, I thought that was only because browsers' parsers ignore minor errors. Seems like a good issue to raise in the js-beautify github.

Comment: @Pete `body` and `head` tags are also optional. The example I wrote is a valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are lots of complains about js-beautify, I'm posting this alternative:

GIT: https://github.com/maxogden/commonjs-html-prettyprinter

DEMO: http://requirebin.com/?gist=45056f6a9b306a14ea3d

CODE:

```
var htmlmodule = require('html');
var str = ' \n <div id="a">\n <span class="b"><span>Hello</span></span><input type="text">\n  \n</div>\n ';
var pretty = htmlmodule.prettyPrint(str);
```

IF this does not work as you intend to, I recommend parsing the HTML string...
for this job you can use this [xmldom](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom) parseFromString... it's really simple.