# How to add indentations in linear DOM string line via NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, string, indentation

I've an svg string in fomat like:

```
    <g id="icons"><g class="cls-1"><path class="cls-2" d="M12,11.43c-2-.45-3.83-.85-2.94-2.54C11.79,3.75,9.79,1,6.92,1S2,3.85,4.77,8.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,11.83,0,12.67,0,14.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,12.67,13.72,11.83,12,11.43Zm2.26-3.94V5.76H12.54V7.49H10.81V9.22h1.73V11h1.73V9.22H16V7.49Z"/></g><path class="cls-3" d="M12,10.43C10,10,8.18,9.58,9.07,7.89,11.79,2.75,9.79,0,6.92,0S2,2.85,4.77,7.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,10.83,0,11.67,0,13.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,11.67,13.72,10.83,12,10.43Zm2.26-3.94V4.76H12.54V6.49H10.81V8.22h1.73V10h1.73V8.22H16V6.49Z"/></g>
```

I need somehow transform it with beauty indentations inserted between each tag (like in original DOM tree).

So, at the end of the process I expect to get next:

```
<g id="icons">
<g class="cls-1">
    <path class="cls-2" d="M12,11.43c-2-.45-3.83-.85-2.94-2.54C11.79,3.75,9.79,1,6.92,1S2,3.85,4.77,8.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,11.83,0,12.67,0,14.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,12.67,13.72,11.83,12,11.43Zm2.26-3.94V5.76H12.54V7.49H10.81V9.22h1.73V11h1.73V9.22H16V7.49Z"
    />
</g>
<path class="cls-3" d="M12,10.43C10,10,8.18,9.58,9.07,7.89,11.79,2.75,9.79,0,6.92,0S2,2.85,4.77,7.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,10.83,0,11.67,0,13.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,11.67,13.72,10.83,12,10.43Zm2.26-3.94V4.76H12.54V6.49H10.81V8.22h1.73V10h1.73V8.22H16V6.49Z"
/>
```

Any ideas about how to make it real or maybe someone knows `npm` lib for such task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet:

It's explained in the following SO Question:
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360414/javascript-how-to-correct-indentation-in-html-string)

```js
var str = ' <g id="icons"><g class="cls-1"><path class="cls-2" d="M12,11.43c-2-.45-3.83-.85-2.94-2.54C11.79,3.75,9.79,1,6.92,1S2,3.85,4.77,8.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,11.83,0,12.67,0,14.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,12.67,13.72,11.83,12,11.43Zm2.26-3.94V5.76H12.54V7.49H10.81V9.22h1.73V11h1.73V9.22H16V7.49Z"/></g><path class="cls-3" d="M12,10.43C10,10,8.18,9.58,9.07,7.89,11.79,2.75,9.79,0,6.92,0S2,2.85,4.77,7.89c.92,1.69-1,2.1-2.94,2.54C.11,10.83,0,11.67,0,13.12v.72H13.83v-.72C13.84,11.67,13.72,10.83,12,10.43Zm2.26-3.94V4.76H12.54V6.49H10.81V8.22h1.73V10h1.73V8.22H16V6.49Z"/></g>';

$('#out').text(process(str));

function process(str) {
    
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.trim();
    
    return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
}

function format(node, level) {
    
    var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
        indentAfter  = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
        textNode;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        
        textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
        node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);
        
        format(node.children[i], level);
        
        if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
            textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
            node.appendChild(textNode);
        }
    }
    
    return node;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: This is a solution for client-side, I'm looking for NodeJS one instead. thanks anyway.