# How to organize generated code and avoid copying format when copying and pasting text in the editor WYSIWYG?

Tags: jquery

I have observed some questions but all are based on the use of a plugin. But I have my own editor so the answers given do not solve my problem.

The issue is that in each tabulation that is given, the code is generated with a `div` container and, the paragraphs in `br` in such a way:

[image]

How to avoid the use of div y, the paragraphs in `br`, instead of them, use only `p` and in an organized way for example:

[image]

And finally

The issue I've got is that whenever you copy and paste something into the editor, it copies over the formatting from wherever you've copied it.

[image]

How can I correct these defects of my editor, here my complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/p87t0aqx/

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @FarzadRastgarSani He used sublime text, but the capture is given to my WYSIWYG editor who used it to create content from my administration panel which is messy as can be seen in the images while the ordinate is about WYSIWYG editor froala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a perfect solution, as there might be a plenty of work to be done to make the WYSIWYG editor truly usable.

**Original Solution:**

What the solution does:

- Format the HTML code on **Code Toggle** before displaying.
- Detect **Enter Key** and apply `<p>` format, otherwise apply `<div>` format.
- On **Clipboard Paste**, intercept the default clipboard pasting behavior and then insert plain text at current editor's cursor position.

```js
$(function() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360414/javascript-how-to-correct-indentation-in-html-string
  function formatHtmlCode(str) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.trim();

    return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
  }

  function format(node, level) {
    var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
      indentAfter = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
      textNode;

    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

      textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
      node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);

      format(node.children[i], level);

      if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
        textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
        node.appendChild(textNode);
      }
    }

    return node;
  }

  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
    switch ($(this).data('role')) {
      case 'p':
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
        break;
        //Specific control for the code button.
      case 'code':
        //enable / disable code mode
        codeMode = !codeMode;
        if (codeMode) {
          // ON: show the code in text mode
          var formattedHtml = formatHtmlCode(htmlDiv.html());

          htmlDiv.css("white-space", "pre");
          htmlDiv.text(formattedHtml);
          //
          var editor = $("#editor")
          editor.addClass("black-bg-colr codeMode")
        } else {
          // OFF: reinterpret the code
          htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal");
          htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
          var editor = $("#editor")
          editor.removeClass("black-bg-colr codeMode")
        }
        break;
      default:
        document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
        break;
    }
  });

  //code mode control
  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");

  htmlDiv.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    }
  });

  htmlDiv.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  });

  //input -> NOT keyup
  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
    //htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
    $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    //$(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html());
  });
  //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function() {
    //var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!codeMode) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
    } else {
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(htmlDiv.text());
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#editControls {
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: silver;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}

.codeMode {
  font-family: Courier New, Source Code Pro Light, Medium, Source Code Pro ExtraLight, Menlo, Consola, Monaco Linux, Consola Regular, Fira Code Regular, DejaVu Sans Mono;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
  border: 0px;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WYSIWYG</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor-wrapper">
    <div id="editControls">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**With Ace Editor:**

```js
$(function() {
  var aceEditor = ace.edit("ace-editor");
  aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
  aceEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
    switch ($(this).data('role')) {
      case 'p':
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
        break;
        //Specific control for the code button.
      case 'code':
        //enable / disable code mode
        codeMode = !codeMode;
        if (codeMode) {
          // ON: show the code in text mode
          var editor = $("#editor");
          var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

          var formattedHtml = html_beautify(htmlDiv.html());

          aceEditor.setValue(formattedHtml, -1);

          editor.css("display", "none");
          $aceEditor.css("display", "block");

        } else {
          // OFF: reinterpret the code
          htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
          var editor = $("#editor");
          var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

          editor.css("display", "block");
          $aceEditor.css("display", "none");

          htmlDiv.html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
        }
        break;
      default:
        document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
        break;
    }
  });

  //code mode control
  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");

  htmlDiv.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    }
  });

  htmlDiv.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  });

  //input -> NOT keyup
  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
    //htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
    $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    //$(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html());
  });
  //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

  aceEditor.getSession().on('change', function() {
    $('.editor-preview').html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
  });

  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function() {
    //var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!codeMode) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
    } else {
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(htmlDiv.text());
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#editControls {
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: silver;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}

.codeMode {
  font-family: Courier New, Source Code Pro Light, Medium, Source Code Pro ExtraLight, Menlo, Consola, Monaco Linux, Consola Regular, Fira Code Regular, DejaVu Sans Mono;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
  border: 0px;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}

#ace-editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WYSIWYG</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ace.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ext-beautify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.3/beautify-html.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor-wrapper">
    <div id="editControls">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
    <div id="ace-editor"></div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**Ace Editor with `<p>` Only:**

```js
$(function () {
    var aceEditor = ace.edit("ace-editor");
    aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    aceEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

    $('#editControls a').click(function (e) {
        switch ($(this).data('role')) {
            case 'p':
                document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
                break;
            //Specific control for the code button.
            case 'code':
                //enable / disable code mode
                codeMode = !codeMode;
                if (codeMode) {
                    // ON: show the code in text mode
                    var editor = $("#editor");
                    var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

                    var formattedHtml = html_beautify(htmlDiv.html());

                    aceEditor.setValue(formattedHtml, -1);

                    editor.css("display", "none");
                    $aceEditor.css("display", "block");

                } else {
                    // OFF: reinterpret the code
                    htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
                    var editor = $("#editor");
                    var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

                    editor.css("display", "block");
                    $aceEditor.css("display", "none");

                    htmlDiv.html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
                }
                break;
            default:
                document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
                break;
        }
    });

    //code mode control
    let codeMode = false;
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");

    htmlDiv.on("paste", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    });

    //input -> NOT keyup
    htmlDiv.on("input", function (e) {
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
        //htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
        //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
        $(".editor-preview").keyup();
        //$(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html());
    });
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    aceEditor.getSession().on('change', function () {
        $('.editor-preview').html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
    });

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function () {
        //var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
        if (!codeMode) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
            $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
        } else {
            //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(htmlDiv.text());
            $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#editControls {
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: silver;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}

.codeMode {
  font-family: Courier New, Source Code Pro Light, Medium, Source Code Pro ExtraLight, Menlo, Consola, Monaco Linux, Consola Regular, Fira Code Regular, DejaVu Sans Mono;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
  border: 0px;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}

#ace-editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WYSIWYG</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ace.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ext-beautify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.3/beautify-html.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor-wrapper">
    <div id="editControls">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
    <div id="ace-editor"></div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Friend, you think it is convenient to use ace.js to bring the generated code to life when the icon is clicked: <>

Comment: Hi, integration with Ace editor is quite straight forward, I have added the Ace editor based solution.

Comment: Hello friend, you can't avoid using `div`, instead of `div` all by 'p', then try replacing the` div` with `p` but the first code is always generated by creating a `div` I don't want to use this tag, everything except that friend.

Comment: I have added solution that only generate `<p>` without `<div>`, please refer to section **Ace Editor with `<p>` Only**.